# What do I do with the "mysterious key"?

Tags: across-the-obelisk

I found a mysterious key in the volcano area. What do I do with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a part of the secret treasure quest which can be redeemed in Act 4. This quest gives you the [currently second most rare achievement in the game](https://steamcommunity.com/stats/1385380/achievements), "Last Piece" for finding Luffy's Hat.

In order to complete it, you must visit certain nodes in a certain order.

1. In the first world, visit "The Lake" node when it's a purple book. You may need to restart a few times for it to be purple, but it seems to be fairly common.  When you get there, choose "search for anything interesting".  You'll find a treasure map.
   Follow the quest nodes throughout the first world.  You'll get some mediocre treasure, and a second treasure map.
   [image: Lake node]
2. (Steps 2 and 3 can be done in any order) In the green world, move to the quest node by buying one of the two boats.  Choose the west pillar, which was shown on the treasure map.  This will give you one of the mysterious keys.
   [image: Green Portal]
3. In the red world, visit and enter the volcano.  After a somewhat difficult fight, you'll get a second mysterious key.
   *(Alternatively, in the blue world, visit the sewers. I don't have an image for this yet)*
   [image: Red Portal]
4. In Act 4, follow the quest markers for both keys. This will lead to an *extremely* difficult fight including two priests.  If you are going a debuff build (poison/bleed/fire etc) I recommend doing the priests lasts.  Even though they are the healers, they have the ability to give all their debuffs to one of your players, which makes them *extremely* dangerous to debuff.
   [image]

Your reward is a treasure chest with some of the most powerful items in the game, including Luffy's Hat, which gives (among other things) every hero two extra cards every turn; and the Magic Mirror which gives one character a 0-cost copy of the first card they play every turn.

Comment: `462322B` is a seed where the starting event is purple.